# Apache mod_security blocking country

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm, mod-security

I used this rule to block country in Mod_security : (I already configured @geoLookup with the maxmide lite database .dat)

```
# Test IP address and block by country code
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "phase:1,chain,id:10,drop,log,msg:'Blocking China IP Address'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq CN"
```

But it doesn't work, no ip logged. I tried with a different country and it does not work.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Rule looks fine. Can you up set SecDebugLog and SecDebugLogLevel and see if anythign shows there. Note this will produce a log of logging so should not be done in production for a busy site.

Comment: More simple and effective, it's use a firewall, and block country on firewall for 80 port. Effective beacuse minor cpu and menory recurses.  IMHO.